# Why jQuery live() does not work?

Tags: javascript, live, jquery

I have the following code which work fine:

```
$('.ui-selectmenu-menu a').click(function() { alert('OK'); });
```

However, if I replace it with:

```
$('.ui-selectmenu-menu a').live('click', function() { alert('OK'); });
```

it does not work.

What could be the reason for that ?

(In my case, `$('.ui-selectmenu-menu a')` elements could be removed and added again during the run.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the class changes e.g. the parent doesn't have `class="ui-selectmenu-menu` then the selector would no longer match, make sure this isn't happening after whatever events you have.

Unlike binding directly to the element, the selector no longer matching will stop a [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) handler from firing for that element's events.

Comment: In my case, the element `$(".ui-selectmenu-menu")` is removed and then created again (with its <a> childs). Is this stops the .live() on `$(".ui-selectmenu-menu a")` from working ? What workaround would you suggest in my case ?

Answer (score 1):

Nick's answer makes sense. But also, check that you have jquery version 1.3 or greater.
`.live()` was added in jquery version 1.3.